# Flip a tooltip orientation to horizontal inside of a vertical stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I get the tooltip to a horizontal direction when is attached to a single control which is inside a stackpanel with it `orientation` property set to vertical?

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.WindowTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WindowTest" Height="450" Width="800">    

    <Grid>       
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="Label"></Label>
            <TextBox Text="Hello world" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="left">
                <TextBox.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}">
                     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </TextBox.ToolTip>
            </TextBox>
            <Label Content="Label2"></Label>
            <Label Content="Label3"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not get what you want.

If you want Hello world to be displayed horizontal instead of vertical.

2 options :

1) Replace the ItemsControl with a Textblock or something else.

2) Change the layout of the item panel of your ItemsControl. Like this :

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

The default behavior of an ItemsControl is to display items in vertical orientation like ListBox, etc. When you bind a string as the itemsSource, it's like you give an array of char. So your collection is composed of char. That's why you get a vertical list of char which is the expected default behavior.